# How to compare two objects and change the key name?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

compare headerObj(field_key) and dataObj(key) and form the result with label from headerObj

```js
const headerObject = [{
    label: 'Code',
    field_key: 'code'
  },
  {
    label: 'Worked Accounts',
    field_key: 'workedAccounts'
  },
  {
    label: 'Contactable Accounts',
    field_key: 'contactableAccounts'
  },
  {
    label: 'Taken By',
    field_key: 'takenBy'
  },
];

const dataObj = [{
    "code": "ABCD",
    "takenBy": "",
    "workedAccounts": 4,
    "contactableAccounts": 3,
  },
  {
    "takenBy": "Ram",
    "workedAccounts": 2,
    "contactableAccounts": 1,
  },
  {
    "takenBy": "krish",
    "workedAccounts": 2,
    "contactableAccounts": 2,
  },
  {
    "code": "XYZ",
    "takenBy": "",
    "workedAccounts": 9,
    "contactableAccounts": 4,
  },
  {
    "Taken By": "Jack",
    "workedAccounts": 5,
    "contactableAccounts": 0,
  },
  {
    "Taken By": "krish",
    "workedAccounts": 4,
    "contactableAccounts": 4,
  }
];

const result = [{
    "Code": "ABCD",
    "Taken By": "",
    "Worked Accounts": 4,
    "Contactable Accounts": 3,
  },
  {
    "Taken By": "Ram",
    "Worked Accounts": 2,
    "Contactable Accounts": 1,
  },
  {
    "Taken By": "krish",
    "Worked Accounts": 2,
    "Contactable Accounts": 2,
  },
  {
    "Code": "XYZ",
    "Taken By": "",
    "Worked Accounts": 9,
    "Contactable Accounts": 4,
  },
  {
    "Taken By": "Jack",
    "Worked Accounts": 5,
    "Contactable Accounts": 0,
  },
  {
    "Taken By": "krish",
    "Worked Accounts": 4,
    "Contactable Accounts": 4,
  }
];

result = filter(headerObj, el =>
    Object.keys(dataObj)?.filter(ele => ele === el.field_key && {[el.field.key]: ele[field.key));
```

Comment: `{[el.field.key]: ele[field.key));` is not correct

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code-- I think it is an unmatched curly brace (`{`/`}`) and an unmatched square bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const headerArray = [
    {
        label: 'Code',
        field_key: 'code',
    },
    {
        label: 'Worked Accounts',
        field_key: 'workedAccounts',
    },
    {
        label: 'Contactable Accounts',
        field_key: 'contactableAccounts',
    },
    {
        label: 'Taken By',
        field_key: 'takenBy',
    },
];

// This is how your header array should be structured
// in the first place
const headerMap = headerArray.reduce((acc, { label, field_key }) => {
    acc[field_key] = label;
    return acc;
}, {});

const dataArray = [
    {
        code: 'ABCD',
        takenBy: '',
        workedAccounts: 4,
        contactableAccounts: 3,
    },
    {
        takenBy: 'Ram',
        workedAccounts: 2,
        contactableAccounts: 1,
    },
    {
        takenBy: 'krish',
        workedAccounts: 2,
        contactableAccounts: 2,
    },
    {
        code: 'XYZ',
        takenBy: '',
        workedAccounts: 9,
        contactableAccounts: 4,
    },
    {
        takenBy: 'Jack',
        workedAccounts: 5,
        contactableAccounts: 0,
    },
    {
        takenBy: 'krish',
        workedAccounts: 4,
        contactableAccounts: 4,
    },
];

const result = dataArray.map((obj) => {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(obj).map((key) => [headerMap[key], obj[key]]));
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have and errors in your example objects, but I think this is what you need:

```
const map = headerObject.reduce((acc, item) => ({...acc, [item.field_key]: item.label}), {});

dataObj.reduce((acc, item) => [
  ...acc,
  Object.keys(item).reduce((curr, key) => ({ ...curr, [map[key]]: item[key] }), {})
], []);
```

at first you need create a map for easy compare keys and values and then map it. Hope this helps.